# var Object = new Object();

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
>> typeof Object
"function"   

>> var Object = new Object();

>> typeof Object
"object"

>> var a = new Object()
TypeError: Object is not a constructor
```

Why it is possible to use "Object" as a valid variable name?

Comment: Object is already an object, perhaps? (And not a constructor for new objects furthermore)

Comment: @rabudde: I believe his question is "why can I do this? - why do I not get something like `SyntaxError: assignment to keyword`?" (as you get in Python 3 for a line like `True = False` - which you could do in Python 2)

Comment: Why do you want to close this question? care to comment?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa: you could make the question a *lot* clearer.

Comment: `var a = {}; typeof(a) === 'object';`

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 3):

`new Object()` will return an object as does `{}`. So yes, `typeof new Object() === "object"`. The constructor is (as any constructor) a function, so `typeof Object === "function"`.

If you replace the constructor with an object, however, then `typeof Object === "object"` since `Object` has become an object like `{}`. It's the same logic as `typeof {} === "object"`.

[`Object` is not a keyword at all.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Comment: aaand so it's no problem to "overload" the function "Object"

Comment: @rabudde: I don't say that; it is certainly bad practice to do so in fact. But technically, it's possible in that it does not raise any errors.

Answer (score 2):

These are the [reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript:

```
break
case
catch
continue
debugger
default
delete
do
else
finally
for
function
if
in
instanceof
new
return
switch
this
throw
try
typeof
var
void
while
with
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"Why "Object" is not a specific keyword?"*

Because it's not defined as such in the specification.

[ECMAScript 7.6.1 Reserved Words](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1)

Answer (score 1):

That your code is valid is controlled by two factors:

- [`Object` is not a "reserved word"](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1).
- Names re-declared in a scope "hide" entities of the same name that were declared in an outer scope. That means that your local variable `Object` may hide the function `Object` that exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done here is 
using Object class Constructor you have declared Object as new variable. 
And when you use Object() it will refer to object declared before named Object.

Comment: He knows that. He wants to know why it's possible, because his intuitive assumption would be that the token `Object` could not be re-used in this context.